How can I annotate my Django queryset with a count of related objects
I have 3 django models; Machine, Component, and Part.
I am trying to annotate a machine queryset to include the count of unique parts used in that machine.
In the example below, ps1 is used to make f1. ps1 and ps2 are used to make f2. f1 and f2 are used to make r1. Therefore, 2 unique parts are used to create r1 and this is the value I want to use to annotate r1. So far my code is outputting 3 in this case.
    # |------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+--------------|
    # | machine    | component           | part           | expected     | result       |
    # |            |                     |                | parts        | parts        |
    # |------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+--------------|
    # | r1         | f1                  | ps1            | 2            | 3            |
    # |            | f2                  | ps1            |              |              |
    # |            |                     | ps2            |              |              |
    # |------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+--------------|


Part has a ManyToManyField of Component.

# part.py
components = models.ManyToManyField("Component", related_name="parts")


Component has several ForeignKeys to Machine.

# component.py
machine_engine = models.ForeignKey("Machine", related_name="engine_components")
machine_transmission = models.ForeignKey("Machine", related_name="transmission_components")

This is the function I am working with to try and accomplish this.
def annotate_machine_query_with_num_parts(machine_query):
    count_subquery = (
        Parts.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef("pk"))
        .annotate(count=Count("id", distinct=True))
        .values("count")
    )

    sum_subquery = (
        Parts.objects.filter(
            Q(component__machine_id=OuterRef("pk"))
        )
        .annotate(count=Subquery(count_subquery))
        .values("count")
        .annotate(num_parts=Sum("count"))
        .values("num_parts")
    )

    return machine_query.annotate(num_parts=Coalesce(sum_subquery, 0))

This works for many test cases but fails when a part is reused by multiple components, as is the case with ps1 here.
I have tried a few things which have resulted in subquery must return a single row errors. I am sure there must be a simpler way to achieve this.
edit:
I have updated the sample from component.py above. I actually have several ForeignKeys from component to machine which define in what way the component is used in the machine.
Based on the comments, I figured I would be able to do the following to handle this:
    machine_query.annotate(
        num_parts=(
            Count("engine_components__parts"), distinct=True) +
            Count("transmission_components__parts"), distinct=True)
        )
    )

The issue I am facing is that a component can be used in both the engine and the transmission, which is causing that components parts to be double counted, because the parts actually exist as distinct in each of the counts.
Is there a solution that can traverse all the relationships, collect the parts, and then apply the distinct before counting?

Please share (relevant parts of) your models.

I think you are overcomplicating things. You can work with distinct=True [Django-doc]:
from django.db.models import Count

Machine.annotate(num_parts=Count('component__parts', distinct=True))


Note: The related_name=… [Django-doc]
is the name of the manager to fetch the related objects in reverse. Therefore
normally the related_name of a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField is plural,
for example components instead of component.


I am having trouble with this proposed solution because the model relationships basically point in the opposite direction. Machine doesn't have a component field. I added the relationship defining fields to the question.

@ChrisParker: it has. If you make a relation, Django automatically adds one in reverse. These relations are not per se "material", a ManyToManyField is in fact not even material in both directions.

@ChrisParker: this is what the related_name='component' in fact does (or more specific related_query_name, but this defaults to related_name if given).

I see, good to know. This solution is working after all

@willem-van-onsem I added an edit which introduces a little more complexity. Any chance you can help again?

@ChrisParker: I think it might be useful to make only one m2m model, that also stores if this is about the transmission, engine, etc. so making the modeling "simpler" and more "linear".


"also stores if this is about the transmission, engine, etc."

Using a through table?

@ChrisParker: yes, exactly, a through table, that also adds a ForeingKey to the "kind" of link.
